# running a rails 4.0.0 app on a rails 3.2.6 system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I developed an app on rails 4.0.0 on my mac at home.
a very good scholarly guy helped me with the last part of it and sent me the zip of my modified project to me this morning.

my linux system that i use to also do rails dev stufs is rails 3.2.6.

i can't get the app to run on it.
when I do a rake db:migrate, I get the following error:

```
ironmantis7x@ironscribe5:~/RoR_projects/mock_devices2$ rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
can't convert String into Hash
/home/ironmantis7x/RoR_projects/mock_devices2/config/routes.rb:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/ironmantis7x/RoR_projects/mock_devices2/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ironmantis7x/RoR_projects/mock_devices2/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
ironmantis7x@ironscribe5:~/RoR_projects/mock_devices2$ ^C
ironmantis7x@ironscribe5:~/RoR_projects/mock_devices2$
```

here is my routes.rb file:

```
MockDevices2::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :devices

  resources :posts

  # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  root 'posts#index'

end
```

can anyone help me understand where i went wrong?

thanks!!

ironmantis7x

Comment: please show your route file

Comment: @Lichtamberg - sorry I forgot this in the oringinal post

Comment: any specific reason that's keeping you from doing a `bundle install` and use Rails 4?

Comment: Yes -- the application at my job (rails app) is using Rails 3.2.6 so I have to use rails 3.2.6.  Our application is pretty large and they are not going to upgrade it because of my sandbox on my local computer ...